# Finding a basis of an image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let f be a linear transformation such that $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4, V = \operatorname{span}(\vec v_1,\vec v_2)\subset\mathbb{R}^3.$$ My question is if I have the matrix $A$ of $f$ and I check the value of $f|_V(\vec v_1)$ and $f|_V(\vec v_2)$ by calculating $A\vec v_1, A\vec v_2 $, are these two vectors $A\vec v_1, A\vec v_2 $ (if they are linearly independent) a basis of an image of $f|_V$? And if yes, then does that imply that $f|_V$ is a monomorphism since $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f|_V)) = \dim(V) = 2$ ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and actually if $\vec v_1,\vec v_2$ are a basis for $V$ then whether $f(\vec v_1),f(\vec v_2)$ are linearly independent or not, they span $f(V)$, so they form a basis unless they *are* linearly dependent, in which case if either is nonzero it forms a basis on its own. You're entirely right about the monomorphism as well, because if we express $f(V)$ as the span of $f(\vec v_1),f(\vec v_2)$ and $V$ as the span of $\vec v_1,\vec v_2$ there is an obvious bijection between the two spaces except in the case of linear dependence as described above.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I understood right the part "they span f(V), so they form a basis unless they are linearly dependent, in which case if either is nonzero it forms a basis on its own." If $f|_V(\vec v_1) and f|_V(\vec v_2)$ are linearly dependent then doest that imply that either of these vectors can be taken as a basis for $im(f|_V)$ and  $dim(im(f|_V)) = 1$ ?

Comment: Exactly! Unless one of them is zero in which case only the other one forms a basis. This condition does not occur in your example because you specify that the images are linearly independent.

Comment: yes, but I added this info to ask about the monomorphism aswell, it's more of a overall question than a specific exercise. Thank you very much :)